# A question about pushforward measures and continuous Borel isomorphisms

Tags: reference-request, real-analysis, measure-theory, geometric-measure-theory, pushforward

It is fairly well known that if $\mu$ and $\nu$ are nonatomic measures on the standard Borel spaces $(X,B)$ and $(Y,C)$ such that $\mu(X)=\nu(Y)$. If $X$ and $Y$ are uncountable, then there exists a Borel isomorphism $f : X \to Y$ such that $f_\# \mu=\nu$.

Keep in mind that if $(X,B)$ and $(Y,C)$ are measurable spaces, $f: X \to Y$ is a measurable map, and $\mu$ is a measure on $B$, then we write $f_\#\mu$ for the push forward measure on $C$, which is defined by $f_\#\mu(A) = \mu(f^{-1}(A))$ for all $A \in C$.

Is there a continuous analog for this? Specifically, considering that Borel isomorphisms need not be continuous, is there anything similar to the result above, but where $f$ is continuous?

Any insights or sources would be valuable.

Comment: If $X$ and $Y$ are Polish spaces with their Borel $\sigma$-algebra, then there exists always a finer Polish topology on $X$ that makes $f$ continuous. I can't think of more one could do.

Comment: True if $X$ and $Y$ are intervals (both closed or both open) on the real line and the support of $\mu$, $\nu$ is $X$, $Y$, respectively. For higher dimensional analogues one should look in geometric measure theory.

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker Thank you for your comment. Do you have a source for that statement?

Comment: @O-Schmo This follows from Theorem 4.59 in the 2006 book "Infinite Dimensional Analysis" by Aliprantis and Border.

Comment: @user95282 I think I can prove this on my own, but do you have a source for that statement and/or a good geometric measure theory book?

Comment: @O-Schmo The result for intervals of reals follows by looking at the probability distribution functions, discussed in any introduction to probability theory on the real line.

Comment: @O-Schmo The Wikipedia article on Geometric measure theory has several book references. Not being an expert in this area, unfortunately I cannot say which one is best.

Answer (score 1):

This is a very good (and also well studied) question, especially for homeomorphisms of measures.

For example, the Haar measures on the zero-dimensional compact groups $\mathbb Z_2^\omega$ and $\mathbb Z_3^\omega$ are not homeomorphic because their sets of values on clopen sets are distinct. More information on homeomorphisms of measures can found in [this paper](https://www.ams.org/journals/tran/2005-357-07/S0002-9947-04-03524-X/S0002-9947-04-03524-X.pdf) of Akin.