# When is a Borel isomorphism $f: X \to \mathbb{R}$ continuous?

Tags: measure-theory

Consider standard Borel space $X$ such that there exists a Borel isomorphism $f:X\to \mathbb{R}$. Under what conditions on $X$ are we ensured that there exists a *continuous* Borel isomorphism $f:X\to \mathbb{R}$?

For instance, if $X$ is a Polish group, then any Borel homomorphism from $X$ to a separable metric space is continuous. (See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polish_space#Polish_groups).) However, is there some way to ensure that there exists a Borel isomorphism $f:X \to \mathbb{R}$ which is also a group homomorphism?

A trivial example would be to consider $X = (\mathbb{R}, +)$. Are there any less stringent assumptions on $X$ such that such a continuous $f$ exists? Or are there perhaps some examples of such $X$?

I've found the related question [A question about pushforward measures and continuous Borel isomorphisms](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/412649/a-question-about-pushforward-measures-and-continuous-borel-isomorphisms), but it's not clear to me how Akin's paper [Good measures on Cantor spaces](https://doi.org/10.1090/S0002-9947-04-03524-X) referenced in Taras Banakh's [answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/414960) relates to this question.

Comment: MathJax note: prefer *MathJax* `*MathJax*` to $\textit{TeX trickery}$ `$\textit{TeX trickery}$` (notice the former uses the correct font, while the latter does not).  I have edited accordingly.

Comment: You seem to use the phrase "standard Borel space" differently than I do. For me (and wikipedia) such a space is given by just its $\sigma$-algebra , with no specified topology. The only way I can understand your question is as asking whether there *exists* a topology on $X$ that provides a continuous $f$ (and agrees with the given Borel structure). But that seems trivial: Just use the given Borel isomorphism to pull back the usual topology of $\mathbb R$ to $X$.

Comment: @AndreasBlass thanks for your comment! Indeed, wikipedia doesn't explicitly define a standard Borel space to be a topological space. (However, [here it does](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borel_set#Standard_Borel_spaces_and_Kuratowski_theorems).) I meant $X$ to be a topological space. I see now that we can always redefine the topology on $X$ such that $f$ is continuous and we still have the same Borel sets. Since $f$ is not unique, it's ambiguous which topology on $X$ we'd end up with. Are there perhaps some examples of $X$ (and its ‘canonical’ topology) such that there is a continuous $f$?

Comment: I'm confuses by your question : The result you mention for polish group isn't for arbitrary bordel map but for group morphism, yet you don't mention group structure at all in the question.

Comment: There is a continuous Borel isomorphism from $(-\infty, 0] \cup (1,\infty)$ onto $\mathbb{R}$ which shifts the right part one unit to the left. I guess there could be a lot of examples of this type. Can you give us more idea of what you were hoping for?

Comment: Or take $X = \mathbb{R}$ with the topology generated by the usual open sets together with the set of all irrationals. A typical open set looks like a standard open set union the irrationals in another standard open set. This $X$ is connected, but the identity map isn't a homeomorphism.